# Lower and upper semicontinuity of the Cartesian product

Tags: general-topology, multivalued-functions, set-valued-analysis

Suppose I am considering set-valued maps $G_i:\Bbb R\to 2^\Bbb R$ which I know are both upper and lower continuous. Does it mean that the product map $G_1\times\dots\times G_n$ is upper and lower continuous?

Comment: Does "$f : \mathbb{R} \to 2^\mathbb{R}$ is upper and lower continuous" mean something like "for all $A \in 2^\mathbb{R}$, $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \subseteq A \}$ and $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \supseteq A\}$ are closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$"?

Answer (score 2):

Lower hemi-continuity is preserved by finite products and upper-hemicontinuity of compact-valued correspondences is too. This can be found in many books, such as Aliprantis & Border.

Generally, the result is not true. Take the correspondence $G(x)=\mathbb{R}\times\{x\}$. The set $$C=\big\{(1/x,x):0<x\leq1\big\}$$ is closed, but

$$\big\{x:G(x)\cap C\neq\emptyset\big\}=(0,1]$$ is not closed. This is taken from Kuratowski's topology book.